# oozie workflow fs:isDir

Tags: hive, oozie

In oozie workflow I am trying to use fs:isDir function but it is not allowing me to pass variable in it.

${fs:isDir(${temp}) eq true}

It's throwing an error that { is illegal character. It is not working ${fs:isDir($temp) eq true}

Please let me know how do I do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
${fs:isDir(temp) == true}
```